# Multistep information collection with reference to price addition or substraction

Tags: forms, webforms, entities, quiz

As I have posted previously, I was trying to built product kit with customization option. But there is no easy solution for that and diving into the coding using drupal commerce or ubercart need understanding of those module first.

So I reviewed the requirement again and saw, checkout is not required. I just have to declare the product kit & gather the information...

Have a look here on this link - [Customize Your Laptop](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=dkdwgy4&model_id=alienware-m17x-r4&c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19)

I have to declare package like this. Where there would be default price for kit which will be sum of all default product. Every kind of product, there would some other option either in radio or checkbox and at time of going through step by step user can give their input and total price would change accordingly.

I will tell you the options which I have till now -

- Webform (But the reference price change would be an issue)
- Quiz (Same problem)
- Form API (Client can't create package from them-self that is the main criteria behind this application)

Can I have some suggestion from someone, like what can be my roadmap or which module can help me with it by some tweaking or their API?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the shopping aspect of the site then I would do the following.

1. Create the content types called the product.
2. Add a field with a drop down with the different steps (Processor, RAM etc)
3. Add a field to add the price.

Create a custom module with formAPI to call these values and do the needful.

Multistep forms would be the way to go. With Ajax to give it some flare.

You can download the [example](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module to see how the form APIs work. The examples you would want to check would be the **form example** and **ajax example**

Comment: Nice suggestion which you gave. But how to change the price on change of the option ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the changed price are you storing it some place or send it via mail or just display it to client?

Comment: I meant...how to set price for the option which I have in there for user to select ?

Comment: You would be getting the price information from the contents and then you can use that in the form..

Comment: For the default selection which I will show to the user first will have sum of all the default selection or some override value..but if he change the selection or check some other option(as in some case he can), price will change accordingly. I need this submission in result...like before submitting I would take the contact details and based on submission user will be contacted..

Comment: Suppose I am keeping 3 radio button where one can be selected then how to define the price for all separately, so that I calculate the summation of all default selection as well as calculate the sum on change?

Comment: you would have the key of the radio button as the price from which you can take it

Comment: But the main thing is...client want to have this functionality so that he can add or remove package when ever he wish...and in this way I think..I need custom module for each package as I have already tried what you have suggested..